# Downconversion Intermodulation Frequencies - Where do they come from?

Tags: modulation, dsp, fourier, intermodulation-products

I recently came across [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mm7WfVzr1ao) video which discusses the downconversion of a signal (referred to as IN) to an Intermediate Frequency (IF) using a Local Oscillator (LO). I'm assuming that all of these signals consist of a simple sinusoid with no other harmonics.

I've been reading a textbook on how receivers in communications systems work and from the discussion in the book, I thought that multiplying the IN signal by the LO would result in two spikes in the frequency domain of the output signal (looking only at the positive half of the domain). One at \$f_{IN}+f_{LO}\$ and one at \$f_{IN}-f_{LO}\$. However, in the video, he mentions that there are several "orders" of intermodulation products that are present at the output. He writes down the following equation in his notes ([here](https://www.qsl.net/w2aew/youtube/RFmixersheterodyne.pdf)) as the general form of these intermodulation products:

[image]

Where m and n can be any integer.

Whenever he displays the frequency domain view of \$f_{out}\$ on his oscilloscope, you can clearly see the intermodulation frequencies that match the form of the equation above. Whenever he changes the LO frequency, you can see some of these intermodulation frequencies shift up and some shift down, which makes me think there's some kind of aliasing going on.

My question is: Where are these intermodulation products coming from? Is there a theoretical explanation for this or do these just pop up as undesirable effects of real systems? Why do we not just see the two spikes that the multiplicative property of the Fourier transform would imply?

Thanks

Comment: The multiply "operator" is a linear operation. But the real "multiplier" is not, because it is "non-linear". http://www.arcticpeak.com/radiopages/intermodulationproducts.htm

Comment: One can use also AppCad from AVAGO Technologies.

Answer (score 3):

For an ideal multiplier using the signal itself will only produce signals with an exponent of 2 or squared term.   The non-linearity of the multiplier is what causes the other harmonics to occur and thus other intermodulation sum and difference results according to the amount of distortion on the linear multiplier.

Mathematically, the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Exponential_function) is one way to express the frequency domain products for a transfer function in the time domain.

Comment: I thought multiplication was already a non-linear operation. What's the difference between an ideal multiplier and a non-linear multiplier? Additionally, how could we predict the magnitude of these intermodulation frequencies beforehand? Do you also have an example of how the Taylor series is used to describe the behavior of a multiplication element?

Comment: Yes very quadratic but like diodes, not always ideal.. If you can do the math, you can predict the IM distortion.